# how to create mysql table names based on the current month and year

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I create mysql event script with the aim to create mysql tables automatically every month. I want **the name of the tables based on the current month and year**. How do I do that?

I am trying this:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` EVENT `event_name` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `currentMonth_currentYear_tableName` (
 `column1` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `column2` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 `column3` DECIMAL( 10, 1 ) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (  `column1` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

Comment: Does this work? `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m_%Y'), '_tableName') (`

Comment: @hargobind, thanks but I get error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(NOW(),`%m_%Y`),`_tableName`) ( `column1` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL , `column2` DAT' at line 4. Problem in here: CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),`%m_%Y`),`_tableName`)

Comment: Try assigning `CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m_%Y'), '_tableName')` to a variable and using the variable where the table name should go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this from an Events declaration, but it seems to work in my query browser:

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m_%Y'), '_tableName (
 `column1` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `column2` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 `column3` DECIMAL( 10, 1 ) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (  `column1` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8'
);
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The idea for CONCAT/PREPARE/EXECUTE was taken from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14401

Answer (score 2):

You can't use expressions or variables as identifiers in SQL. Identifiers names must be constant at the time you prepare the query.

To make a variable table name like you describe, you'll have use format an SQL statement as as string, and then use [PREPARE and EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to run it.

In other words, the expression or variable must resolve to a constant identifier name *before* you prepare the statement.